# Error with sphinx php api class used in symfony2 as a service

Tags: php, symfony, sphinx

I use sphinx php api as a service in a symfony2 project when I want to search a term in an index i got this warning

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/domain.com/Symfony2/src/project/myBundle/services/SphinxClient.php line 997**

this is the line 997

```
foreach ( $this->_weights as $weight )
```

so I added a test befor foreach() like this     if(!empty($this->_weights))

the same error appaires in each foreach so I added the same test.

then an other error appaires

**Notice: Undefined property: prject\MyBundle\services\SphinxClient::$_socket in in /var/www/domain.com/Symfony2/src/project/myBundle/services/SphinxClient.php line 563**

I was loking for the problem origin for hours.

thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In sphinxapi.php file used old constructor.

```
Delete string ( near 430 )

function SphinxClient()
```

and write:

```
public function __construct()
```

and all very well.

Don't forget to set namespace in file (I renamed sphinxapi.php to SphinxClient.php) and write in begin it:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Sphinx;
```

Your path may be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the source of the file, not a lot can do to help.

IN the standard sphinxapi.php class that comes with sphinx the varaiables are all class variables, so $this->_weigths is an array. Maybe that was missed when it was poted to Symfony